# Do Python regular expressions allow embedded options?

Tags: python, regex

In particular, I'd like to know if I can specify an embedded option in the pattern string that will enable multiline mode.  That is, typically with Python regular expressions multiline mode is enabled like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'foo', re.MULTILINE)
```

I'd like a way to get multiline matching by specifying it in the pattern string, rather than using the re.MULTILINE option.  You can do this in Java with the embedded (?m) expression.  e.g.,

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?m)foo')
```

Is this possible in Python, or am I required to use the re.M option?  And in general, is there a good reference for embedded pattern options in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

> **`(?iLmsux)`** (One or more letters from the set 'i',
>   'L', 'm', 's', 'u', 'x'.)
>
> The group
>   matches the empty string; the letters
>   set the corresponding flags: [`re.I`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.I)
>   (ignore case), [`re.L`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.L) (locale
>   dependent), [`re.M`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.M) (multi-line), [`re.S`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.S)
>   (dot matches all), [`re.U`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.U) (Unicode
>   dependent), and [`re.X`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.X) (verbose), for
>   the entire regular expression. (The
>   flags are described in [Module
>   Contents](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#contents-of-module-re).)
>
> **This is useful if you wish
>   to include the flags as part of the
>   regular expression, instead of passing
>   a flag argument to the `compile()`
>   function.**
>
> Note that the `(?x)` flag changes how
>   the expression is parsed. It should be
>   used first in the expression string,
>   or after one or more whitespace
>   characters. If there are
>   non-whitespace characters before the
>   flag, the results are undefined.